# Updating Measure in SSAS Cube

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, cube

Is there a way to create a new measure in an SSAS (SQL Server Analysis Server) cube, other than modifying and re-running the entire CREATE XMLA cube script?

Tried the following stand-alone MDX queries:

**Query #1**

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.Measures.[TestMeasure] AS 
NULL;
```

**Result:**

```
Executing the query ...
No cube specified. A cube must be specified for this command to work.
Execution complete
```

**Query #2**

```
CREATE MEMBER [CubeName].Measures.[TestMeasure] AS 
NULL;
```

**Result:**

```
Executing the query ...
Execution complete
```

Note: Query #2 executes but measure does not appear in "CubeName" cube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CREATE MEMBER is scoped, so those members don't persist outside of your session/query.

In order to create a new permanent calculated member on your CUBE you need to use an ALTER XMLA script, not a CREATE XMLA script.

One example, shamelessly pilfered from the web:

```
<Alter AllowCreate="true" ObjectExpansion="ExpandFull" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>CVCC</DatabaseID>
    <CubeID>CVCC</CubeID>
    <MdxScriptID>MDXScript</MdxScriptID>
  </Object>
  <ObjectDefinition>
    <MdxScript>
      <ID>MDXScript</ID> 
      <Name>MDXScript</Name>
      <Commands>
        <Command>
          <Text> <!–if you want to figure out what to paste below build the calculation in visual studio then look at the ‘script view’–>
            CALCULATE;
            CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[MEASURES].[TestMeasure]
            AS **Your calc goes here**;
          </Text>
        </Command>
      </Commands>
    </MdxScript>
  </ObjectDefinition>
</Alter>
```

Comment: Thanks, the above worked. If measure logic changes, does the cube have to be re-processed for data changes to take effect?

Comment: No, all calculated members are (naturally) calculated on the fly for every value. So you generally want to save these for just calculations on your existing measures (1.25 * [Sales], [Sales]/[# of Customers], etc.) rather than deep-level dimension / attribute based calculations, as you don't take advantage of any your cube's aggregations.

Comment: It's important to mention--any existing measures should be included along with the new measure. Otherwise, it appears existing measures are removed ;-)

Comment: If a cube is being processed, does running an ALTER cube script with updated MDX impact processing at all?

Comment: No, once a cube is in processing state, any changes to its XMLA (such as removing a dimension or renaming a column) are just that, XML changes only, and won't take affect until you re-process the cube. This is the same as modifying the cube in Visual Studio - those changes are made to the XMLA in your client, and you can deploy the changes but not process, and the XMLA is deployed to the server, so your cube can be in a processed state with one XMLA definition but have another XMLA definition stored.

Comment: If the change involves updating existing measure logic, any calculation changes should be seen immediately when running an ad-hoc MDX query, correct?

Comment: Correct, but of course if you're mid-processing many of the measures you're probably using in the calculated measure will be unavailable.